# How to select multiple ranges seperated by group id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I need to create a comma delimited list of values for each group id in a table and fill in any missing values but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
I'm using Server 2016.

my table:

```
  id  |  group_id  |  value  
------+------------+---------
   1  |         1  |    15
   2  |         1  |    16
   3  |         1  |    20
   4  |         2  |    12
   5  |         2  |    15
   6  |         3  |     8
```

expected output:

```
 group_id  |         list
-----------+-----------------------
        1  |  '15,16,17,18,19,20'
        2  |  '12,13,14,15'
        3  |  '8'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternate way. Create a function that takes start and end numbers and generates missing numbers.

```
create function dbo.get_list(@start int, @end int)
returns varchar(1000)
as begin
    declare @retval varchar(1000);
    set @retval = cast(@start as varchar(1000));
    set @start = @start + 1;

    while @start <= @end
    begin
        set @retval = @retval + ',' + cast(@start as varchar(1000));
        set @start = @start + 1;
    end;

    return @retval
end
```

Once that is done, write this SQL:

```
select group_id, dbo.get_list(min(value), max(value))
from test
group by group_id
```

**Result**

```
group_id  list
--------  ------------------
1         15,16,17,18,19,20
2         12,13,14,15
3         8
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a recursive CTE is a good approach:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values (1, 1, 15),
                   (2, 1, 16),
                   (3, 1, 20),
                   (4, 2, 12),
                   (5, 2, 15),
                   (6, 3, 8)
           ) v(  id, group_id, value )
     ),
     cte as (
      select t.group_id, min(t.value) as value, max(t.value) as maxvalue, convert(varchar(max), min(t.value)) as vals, 1 as lev
      from t
      group by t.group_id
      union all
      select cte.group_id, value + 1, maxvalue, concat(vals, ',', value + 1), lev + 2
      from cte
      where value < maxvalue
     )
select cte.group_id, cte.vals
from (select cte.*, max(cte.lev) over (partition by cte.group_id) as maxlev
      from cte
     ) cte
where lev = maxlev
order by group_id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e374994659992cc67a4bacf5c22896e5) is a db<>fiddle.